All view not "centered" when switching
This is not really a "problem", but annoying...
Everything in my model is centered around the world origin.
In Object mode, I see the model in any view using the Num pad keys correctly.
But then when I change a view like front to Back, or L to R, or Top to Bottom, the world origin (along with the model) shifts or jumps L to R or up or down.
The view is oriented along the axis's in all views correctly, but why is the world origin shifting/bouncing around like that when I change the view? I'd expect the model to simply flip but with the world origin staying in exactly the same place?  Or is this world-origin-shifts-when-changing-views designed behavior?
As said, this is not really a "problem" merely annoying. So how can keep the world origin from bouncing around when a view change is made?
Thanks.
I should mention I'm on v2.9 (for reasons, so I can't update to later versions -- if this is a bug that was fixed)
Is this world origin jump/shift when changing views normal?

I think it depends on your Navigation settings. I.E. with Obrit Around Selection enabled, when you switch viewpoint, the view tries to rotate around the active object's origin:

I'm not sure of what it does when this is enabled, perhaps it "flips the whole screen" so to speak.

This is so IF the object's origin + world origin are in the same place. But, if the obj is not centered on the World Origin, but its origin IS, then you can see the "shifting view" shifting behavior.
I discovered another thing... if I use Shift C in object mode, then the view zooms out to " some" distance, then the back front flip view stays "centered" even when I zoom in!   ALSO, in prefs:  INPUT/NDOF, changed Nav from Free to Orbit..
Seems to now lock the center view flip from back to front views.

I did not say this option makes it rotate around the world origin, I only said it makes it rotate around the active object origin, and my GIF highlights that very well when going Top viewpoint. And I gave this as an example of what Navigation settings can do, not an exhaustive list of how the viewport behaves in different scenarios ;)

If all you need is to "flip the model" as you mentioned in your question, the solution is quite simple, enable this option and don't let your object's origins get lost in the void, they need attention and love

"I did not say this option makes it rotate around the world origin, I only said it makes it rotate around the active object origin," -- this is true IF the OBJ is ALSO centered on its origin.  If Obj, and OBJ origins are centered, then yes, I see what you display.
My question is different: If OBJ + orig NOT centered, but Orgi is on World center, then I do not see your clips displayed behavior, but rather the shifting view I wrote in my OP.
How to keep view centered on an OBJs origin, when the OBJ is not centered on its origin?  (your clip shows OBJ + Orig both centered).
